# Variable in html.tpl.php

Tags: theming, 6

This seemingly simple task proved more difficult than I imagined.. I'm trying to get a variable from themename_preprocess_html to my html.tpl.php.

The code I have in my template.php file:

```
<?php
function themename_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['test'] = "Hello world!";
}
```

And in my html.tpl.php file I have:

```
<?php print($test); ?>
```

Unfortunately, the variable isn't displayed in the page. It says:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: test in include()
```

I'm trying to do this so I can use node fields to determine variables in my stylesheet.

Is there any way I can print all available variables in my html.tpl.php?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache since adding the preprocess function?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! But yes, did that.

Comment: Did you replace 'themename' above with your actual theme name?

Comment: Haha, yes, did that. Is it case sensitive though? If my name is "ThemeName" does "themename_preprocess_html" work?

Comment: `get_defined_vars()` is what you're looking for for the debugging by the way

Comment: Thanks, the get_defined_vars displays a lot of variables, but nothing containing the "Hello World!" value.

Comment: The way you did it should work, so there has to be some other reason it is not working. Double check all the standard stuff, like is it uploaded, clear the cache a few more times, is there a spelling mistake, is the themename correct, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll doublecheck everything I can think of.

Comment: Had my template.php file in my templates folder.. Guess the greenness should be showing by now.. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

Try using get_defined_vars() to get the list of all the variables on a page.

> get_defined_vars — **Returns an array of all defined variables**

Source - http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php